# Replacing a char in string with any letter

Tags: java, regex, wildcard

I'm looking for a way to add a wildcard char to a string so I can search from approximate matches, so if I search through my list of strings for the word "b*ke" (where * is the wildcard), I will get {bake, bike, byke, boke} back, is this possible in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have look for "regular expressions" that is you need.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "b[a-z]{1}ke";
final String string = "bake, bike, byke, boke";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have suggested the use of `b.ke` as a regex, which seems closer to what OP wants. Or maybe `b[a-z]ke`.

Comment: Also you don't group anything in your regex, so displaying each group associated to their group index seems rather pointless. Maybe you wanted to count the matches instead?

Answer (score 0):

All is true

```
    System.out.println("bike".matches("b.ke"));
    System.out.println("bake".matches("b.ke"));
    System.out.println("b1ke".matches("b.ke"));

    System.out.println("b123ke".matches("b.+ke"));
    System.out.println("b[wait_for_it]ke".matches("b.+ke"));
```